# Scala ProcessBuilder Piping is Slow

Tags: performance, scala, process, pipe

It's easier to show by example:

```
$ dd if=/dev/urandom of=test.raw bs=1M count=100
100+0 records in
100+0 records out
104857600 bytes (105 MB) copied, 6.50489 s, 16.1 MB/s

$ gzip test.raw

$ time gunzip -k test.raw.gz
0.54s user   4MB memory   99% cpu   0.612 total - gunzip -k test.raw.gz 

$ time cat test.raw.gz | gunzip -c > /dev/null
0.00s user   4MB memory   11% cpu   0.500 total - cat test.raw.gz
0.48s user   4MB memory   99% cpu   0.499 total - gunzip -c > /dev/null
```

And in Scala, things work fine without pipes, but with pipes...

```
scala> import java.io.File; val t2,t1 = 0.0

scala> t1 = System.nanoTime; "gunzip -k test.raw.gz".!; t2 = System.nanoTime; "rm -f test.raw".!; println((t2-t1)/1e9)
0.547709904

scala> t1 = System.nanoTime; ("cat test.raw.gz" #| "gunzip -c" #> new File("/dev/null")).!; t2 = System.nanoTime; "rm -f test.raw".!; println((t2-t1)/1e9)
2.806807235
```

So using Scala's ProcessBuilder piping seems to slow things by a factor of >5 here. Whereas I would naively assumed it would use Unix named pipes on the backend to give nearly the same performance.

So (a): Why is it slow? (b): How can I make it faster?

Thanks!

Comment: Try `strace -r -f -efile scala` to record the system calls.  Maybe scala is not creating pipes directly between `cat` and `gunzip`, or something.  `-efile` might not show you enough, so maybe `-eclone,execve,open,close,dup,dup2`.